# System side programming - Which language?

Tags: java, python, programming-languages

I have few questions over System side programming.

1. Can Python be used for both Web and System like perl.
2. Which language would you prefer me. I have a little knowledge on JavaScript and Java.
3. If i want to develop a compiler what should i know and where should i start.

Comment: do you mean server-side programming?? or systems programming as in operating systems and embedded systems??

Comment: What programming languages should you learn? I don't know. What problems do you want to solve?

Comment: both... server and system side programming, does python support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Use a language that the people around you use.
3. You should know about lexing, parsing, symbol tables, abstract syntax trees, optimisation, intermediate languages, stack-based and register-based architectures, code generation, object file formats, linkers, loaders, etc. There are many resources available in other questions about building compilers here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd definitely go with Python. It's an excellent language for just about everything, especially suitable for web/system development. Learning Python was the best thing I ever did. I used Java/PHP for a few years and I never look back. I reached a higher level of competency, faster with Python than any other language I've tried to learn.

As far as developing compilers go, you'll be in good company with the [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) folks, so that's all the more reason to learn the language. PyPy is both a fast Python interpreter implementation (with JIT) and an advanced compiler/framework for implementing dynamic languages.

Comment: Admittedly I'm pretty biased towards Python, I absolutely love the language, it's such a pleasure to use.

Answer (score 1):

**sure BASH** and one full featured scripting language. I prefer Perl, but it is up to you.

for the 3.) You should study bison or yacc, lex, and/or any other grammar-parsers (compiler-compilers).